# Javascript: How to be the very first receiver of a mouse/key event

Tags: javascript, chromium

I'd like to recognize any mouse input within a website before any other object has a chance of processing it. 
Is there a *native solution* to this?

Why do I need to get it first?
The site uses `event.stopPropagation()` on some mouse events. I want to see these events before they are propagated

**Notes:**

- I case specifically about chromium. There is no need for cross browser support; But I'd like to avoid chromium *hacking*.
- `window.addEventListener ("mousedown", ...)` doesn't work; it would receive events after other elements already stopped their propagation
- `document.body.addEventListener ("mousedown", ...)` doesn't work; it would receive events after other elements already stopped their propagation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify `useCapture` (the third parameter in `addEventListener`) as `true`:

```js
window.addEventListener('mousedown', function(){
  console.log("first")
})

window.addEventListener('mousedown', function(){
  console.log("second") //should fire first
}, true)

window.addEventListener('mousedown', function(){
  console.log("third")
})
```